# Bootstrap gallery

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys so I have this gallery template on bootstrap:

```
<div class="container gallery-container">

    <h1>Bootstrap 3 Gallery</h1>

    <p class="page-description text-center">Clean Layout With Minimal Styles</p>

    <div class="tz-gallery">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="lightbox" href="../images/park.jpg">
                        <img src="../images/park.jpg" alt="Park">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="lightbox" href="../images/bridge.jpg">
                        <img src="../images/bridge.jpg" alt="Bridge">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="lightbox" href="../images/tunnel.jpg">
                        <img src="../images/tunnel.jpg" alt="Tuneel">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="lightbox" href="../images/coast.jpg">
                        <img src="../images/coast.jpg" alt="Coast">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="lightbox" href="../images/rails.jpg">
                        <img src="../images/rails.jpg" alt="Rails">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="lightbox" href="../images/traffic.jpg">
                        <img src="../images/traffic.jpg" alt="Traffic">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I changed the photos and the description of every photo but the problem is that 2 photos go offgrid (the last one and the one before it). I tried changing the size of every photo and the text that I added but it was in vain. Are there other things that I could try?

Comment: Try setting the `max-height` to something fixed for all images eg: `max-wdith: 200px;`. May be your images are not of same dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML layout looks okay. The div's themselves appear to resize responsively.

However if your images are too big for the div containers then the images will spill outside of the div.

Bootstrap has a class for making images responsive so they won't spill outside of the container. This class is `img-responsive` (bootstrap 3) or `img-fluid` (bootstrap 4)

```
<a class="lightbox img-responsive" href="../images/park.jpg"><img src="../images/park.jpg" alt="Park"></a>
```

That said, the best way to prevent this issue will be to make sure that your images are the correct resolution.